# Hot to fill a listView which is in another Form?

Tags: c#

I want to show a new form with a listView, in this listView I want to show the delete records (from a query), if anybody need more information, I can give it.

At this point, I fill a list with the records that I will delete and call the function that is locate in another form to show the listView.

```
public partial class Documento : MaterialForm
{
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            using (adAcerosOPEntities dbLocal = new adAcerosOPEntities())
            {
                String qDocumento = "";

                var remisiones = (dbLocal.Database.SqlQuery<datosConsulta>(qDocumento)).ToList();
                List<Documento> listDato = new List<Documento>();
                
                    foreach (var x in remisiones)
                    {
                        listDato.Add(new Documento { idRem = x.CIDDOCUMENTO });
                        listDato.Add(new Documento { serie = x.CSERIEDOCUMENTO });
                        listDato.Add(new Documento { folio = x.CFOLIO });
                        listDato.Add(new Documento { cliente = x.CCODIGOCLIENTE });
                        listDato.Add(new Documento { fecha = x.CFECHA });
                    }
                
                msgRemisiones ms = new msgRemisiones();
                ms.DialogResult(listDato);
            }
        }
}
```

This is my Form2, I can access to the data from the list.
The problem is when the form Shows, it appers the ListView but empty. I don't know where is the problem. I followed tutorials.

```
public partial class msgRemisiones : MaterialForm
{
        public void DialogResult(List<Documento> doc)

        {
            msgRemisiones ms = new msgRemisiones();
            tbRemisiones.View = View.Details;
            foreach (var v in doc)
            {
                ListViewItem lv = new ListViewItem(v.idRem.ToString());
                lv.SubItems.Add(v.serie);
                lv.SubItems.Add(v.folio.ToString());
                lv.SubItems.Add(v.cliente);
                lv.SubItems.Add(v.fecha);
                tbRemisiones.Items.Add(lv);
            }

            ms.Show();

        }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is this WinForms or WPF?

Comment: WIndowForms. My bad to say both

Comment: What is meant by both? is it WinForm or WPF because both have different binding options to ListView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started trying to work with your code, but it is very confusing.

This is the pattern I would normally use to populate a list control in a form.

First, populate the list.

```
List<Documento> listDato = new List<Documento>();

using (adAcerosOPEntities dbLocal = new adAcerosOPEntities())
{
    String qDocumento = "";

    var remisiones = (dbLocal.Database.SqlQuery<datosConsulta>(qDocumento)).ToList();
            
    foreach (var x in remisiones)
    {
        listDato.Add(new Documento { 
            idRem = x.CIDDOCUMENTO,
            serie = x.CSERIEDOCUMENTO,
            folio = x.CFOLIO,
            cliente = x.CCODIGOCLIENTE,
            fecha = x.CFECHA 
        });
    }
}
```

Then create the form. Pass the list data as an argument to the form constructor.

```
msgRemisiones ms = new msgRemisiones(listDato);
```

Show the form.

```
ms.Show();
```

The form looks like this.

```
public partial class msgRemisiones : MaterialForm
{
    private List<Documento> listDato;

    public msgRemisiones(List<Documento> listDato) 
    {
        this.listDato = listDato;
    }
    
    // Populate the list control in the Form Load event.
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Documento v in this.listDato)
        {
            ListViewItem lv = new ListViewItem(v.idRem.ToString());
            lv.SubItems.Add(v.serie);
            lv.SubItems.Add(v.folio.ToString());
            lv.SubItems.Add(v.cliente);
            lv.SubItems.Add(v.fecha);
            tbRemisiones.Items.Add(lv);
        }
    }
```